# Nested Case Statement - Pulling the wrong value

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested, switch-statement, case

Here is my syntax/question

```
,CASE   WHEN nullif(ltrim(A),'') IS NOT NULL OR nullif(ltrim(B),'') IS NOT NULL THEN NULL                                                                                       
        WHEN nullif(ltrim(C),'') IS NOT NULL        THEN (
                                                        CASE    WHEN nullif(MM,'') IS NOT NULL THEN MM
                                                                WHEN NN IS NOT NULL THEN XX                                                     
                                                                WHEN NN IS NULL THEN concat(UPPER(YY), ' ', UPPER(XX))      
                                                                END
                                                        )
        WHEN nullif(ltrim(D),'') IS NOT NULL OR nullif(ltrim(E),'') IS NOT NULL THEN concat(UPPER(XX), ' ', UPPER(YY))          
        ELSE ' '
        END as 'Data_Item'
```

We have a series of statements to evaluate. 
If fields `A` OR `B` are not null then we pull `NULL`

if field `C` is not null then we evaluate a nested case statement and this is where something is off with my code.

if field `C` is not null we should evaluate field `MM` if `MM` is not null we should return `MM` (this is what i should be getting but i'm not).

we continue to evaluate, if `NN` is not null we pull `XX`

if `NN` is null we concatenate  `YY space XX`

and lastly if field `D` is not null or field `E` is not null then we concatenate fields `XX space YY`.

else we simply return a space
then end

--

In short, its a semi-complex series case statement, if the second scenario is true we have to evaluate like 3 or 4 nested statements. Till we find what is true.

for whatever reason my data is always returning the last statement (D is true) rather than the nested one.

Comment: `case` is an expression - not a statement :)

Comment: `when nullif(ltrim(A),'') IS NOT NULL` can be simplified to `when A <> ''` as empty strings and spaces compare equal.

Comment: Post some sample data and the expected results please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your CASE simplified:

```
CASE   
   WHEN A <> '' OR B <> ''
      THEN NULL                                                                                    
   WHEN C <> ''
      THEN CASE    
              WHEN MM <> '' THEN MM
              WHEN NN IS NOT NULL THEN XX                                                     
              WHEN NN IS NULL THEN Concat(Upper(YY), ' ', Upper(XX))     
           END
   WHEN D <> '' OR E <> ''
      THEN Concat(Upper(XX), ' ', Upper(YY))          
   ELSE ' '
END
```

Seems to match your logic ...

Comment: That is the issue, if my logic matches ... why am I not getting the expected results (in like a handful of scenarios). I can't figure this out.